# method(hash) works, hash.method fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

How do I call a custom helper method on a hash in rails?
Below is a simplified example of my challenge.

The following method works when I call **last_key(my_hash)**

```
  def last_key(hash)
    hash.keys.last
  end
```

This method fails when I call **my_hash.first_key**

```
  def self.first_key
    self.keys.first
  end
```

**undefined method for first_key for hash** is the response I get for using this and a couple other permutations of code.

Why doesn't this work and what is the method syntax I need to have **my_hash.first_key** function correctly?

Comment: class Hash;

  def first_key;
    keys.first;
  end;

end

Comment: no need of self with either of methods first_key and keys.

Answer (score 4):

This is a class method (`self.something`) but you need an object method:

```
class Hash

  def first_key
    self.keys.first
  end

end

a = {'s' => 1, 'b'=> 2}
a.first_key # => "s"
```

Comment: It's important to remember that `self` in the context of a method definition inside a class refers to the class and not some theoretical instance like it would inside an instance method.

Comment: class Hash;

  def first_key;
    keys.first;
  end;

end

Comment: no need of self with method names either first_key or keys.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `self.` from the method definition, otherwise it become class method.

```
  def first_key
    self.keys.first
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the hash class in order to implement the new instance method **some_method**.
That can be done as follows:

```
class Hash

  def some_method
    # your code here
  end

end
```

And you would be able to use. 
    a_hash.some_method